# How do i mask the email in salesforce using formula field

Tags: salesforce

How to find  **i mask the email in salesforce using formula field?**

Suppose i have an object is data type is email
using formula field i have to mask it as ****@****.***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this: LPAD(RIGHT(EMAIL, 4), LEN(EMAIL), '*')

RIGHT takes the last 4 characters from the EMAIL

LPAD adds (EMAIL character length - 4) '*' characters on the left of the string

Comment: It is working i have show at ui side if suppose email id is abcd@gmail.com i have to show maksing as     ****@***.***

Comment: Create a formula field